# Adding an local account user with a different IP in Server 2016

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012

I might be asking for impossible , but I'm not quite sure how the network adapter is used when having multiple users. I'm assuming all users use the same network adapter and it's settings , but what I want to know is the following;
Is it possible to assign another IP address  to a new local account user on my Server 2016? I have a /28 IP block and I'd like every user to use a different IP address. I've looked upon the GPO but to no avail. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Just trying to clarify based on what you wrote: you want when user login to your Windows Server 2016 - the server will change the network card IP address to a different IP address?

Comment: No, users don't have IPs. Systems do.

Comment: @Darius Yes , while keeping the other IP addresses assigned to other logged in users. I realize this is not possible , because if the network card IP changes , it changes for every user , but could I add a virtual network adapter that can utilize the second IP and assign it to a new user?

Comment: .... er... as @FrankThomas has said, System (or specifically NIC) has IP address. You... usually can't have multiple IPs assigned onto 1 NIC (I may be wrong). What is the goal of this? What are you trying to achieve? Reason I'm asking is - the Windows Server itself has an IP for users to connect to (say connecting via remote desktop) - and that would be the IP for the system. Connected users will not (and should not) change that IP - or else the next user who uses the IP address will not be able to connect to it.

Comment: @Darius the goal is to achieve a different IP per user that uses a specific application on my server where there can't be 2 users on the same IP using the application. I know I suck at explaining but I just want a second user to use a second IP , third user to use third IP etc. Just as you would go assign a different IP to each VM , I want to do that for each of my users on a single server.

Comment: @madnoob I don't think what you want is possible. If you simply want to ensure no user tried to login twice (using the same login/IP) - then simply filter it out at your application based on username/password rather than IP address? Or if you want to lock down your application to only white-list some IP address to use your application - whitelist the server IP will get you that security, and then the double-login prevention can be done based on username?

Comment: @Darius you missed my point. Let's say for example there is an user named test on the local server s1. Test user has an IP address of 192.168.1.2 . Now there's a second user named test2 on the local server s1 . What I want is to assign a 192.168.1.3 IP address to the test2 user on the same s1 local server , while preserving the first IP for the first user test.

Comment: @madnoob I am quite sure now what you wanted is not possible. Unless your S1 server is running some sort of separate VM that your user are actually logging into (something similar to VMWare Horizon) - and then yes each VM created (for each user logging in) can have separate IP. But if they are just logging into the server "as is" without any virtualization software - then no.

Answer (score 2):

No, Windows will not allow you to control IP addressing by logged in user.

When you assign multiple IPs to a nic in windows, the system will send outbound traffic from that NIC on its Primary IP. Here is a description of the algorithm used to determine the primary IP: https://secura.cloud/technical-insight/windows-server/set-primary-ip-address-windows-server-2012

There is then the additional problem of how the user contacts the server to login in the first place, if you expect the IP to change as soon as they do.

So, even if you set up a scripty solution to reassign the primary IP upon login, the issue of how they login initially is unsurmountable without changes to the way the server handles remote logins over TCP.

Comment: I assume the server's IP address doesn't _change_ in OP's plan; the server could select a per-user address for _outgoing_ connections (based on the process owner sid) without affecting incoming ones or other active users. (This would be easily doable on Linux at least.)

Comment: Check the link in my answer. Windows will select a Primary IP per nic, and it will pretty much always be the address with the lowest (decimal) value for the most signifigant bits of the host portion of the IP address. see more here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/969029/the-functionality-for-source-ip-address-selection-in-windows-server-2008-and-in-windows-vista-differs-from-the-corresponding-functionality-in-earlier-versions-of-windows